# Local Npm module "grunt-legacy-util" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, webstorm

i have a problem with `grunt serve`,(i dont know if it's normal) `grunt serve` said me "works without errors" but the first message is local npm module "grunt-legacy-util" not found. Is it installed?", i need to delete node_modules folder and make npm install to can work with the server. i do grunt update, npm install grunt-legacy-util, npm install,npm update, but say same message...i use angularjs make with yeoman and webstorm, any idea please?

Comment: Is there any error message on any install/update?

Comment: some warnings but no errors i saw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a sudo command on it as perhaps the file isn't accessible/hidden (for some odd reason).

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-legacy-util
```

Check out this GitHub post should that not work: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1165

It could also be that your NPM that is installed globally is clashing with the NPM in your root directory. Though unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
npm update

Answer (score 0):

The running this following commands again fixed it for me:

```
npm install -g bower,
npm install -g grunt-cli,
bower install,
npm install.
```